# Dynamic Linq Query on data table

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq

I have  two  data table  say cSVData and sqlData i  want  to  compare this  two  data tables  record is  it  same  or  not  so  i am  using  this Query

```
        var matched = from table1 in cSVData.AsEnumerable()
                      join table2 in sqlData.AsEnumerable() on 
                      table1.Field<string>("GlobalRank") equals table2.Field<string>("GlobalRank")
                      where
                      table1.Field<string>("GlobalRank") == table2.Field<string>("GlobalRank") 
                      || table1.Field<string>("TldRank") == table2.Field<string>("TldRank") 
                      || table1.Field<string>("Domain") == table2.Field<string>("Domain")
                      ||  table1.Field<string>("TLD") == table2.Field<string>("TLD")
                      || table1.Field<string>("RefSubNets") == table2.Field<string>("RefSubNets")
                      || table1.Field<string>("RefIPs") == table2.Field<string>("RefIPs")
                      || table1.Field<string>("IDN_Domain") == table2.Field<string>("IDN_Domain")
                      || table1.Field<string>("IDN_TLD") == table2.Field<string>("IDN_TLD")
                      || table1.Field<string>("PrevGlobalRank") == table2.Field<string>("PrevGlobalRank")
                      || table1.Field<string>("PrevTldRank") == table2.Field<string>("PrevTldRank")
                      || table1.Field<string>("PrevRefSubNets") == table2.Field<string>("PrevRefSubNets")
                      select table1;
```

But this  table columns name  must be  dynamic means   in  where  clause  it should  take  all  column name

Comment: If you test on `"GlobalRank"` since you are using a join, you will get every join row and the rest of the conditions don't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `cSVData` and `sqlData` sources are `DataTables`, you should be able to step through the columns using lambda syntax:

```
var match = from table1 in cSVData.AsEnumerable()
            join table2 in sqlData.AsEnumerable() on
            table1.Field<string>("GlobalRank") equals table2.Field<string>("GlobalRank")
            select new { table1, table2 };
foreach (var colname in cSVData.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(c => c.ColumnName))
    if (colname != "GlobalRank")
        match = match.Where(both => both.table1.Field<string>(colname) == both.table2.Field<string>(colname));

match = match.Select(both => both.table1);
```